# Changing the primary key of a SharePoint list?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, database-design, ms-access-2010

I have three SharePoint lists that are linked to an Access 2010 database. I'm trying to write a query that will pull different columns of data from each table and display them together. I wanted to change the primary key of the list so that instead of being 1,2,3, etc. it would be a certain code (16435, 15350, etc.). The five-digit codes would be standard across each table, and I was thinking it would be easier to pull the data if that were the primary key.

How do I change it in SharePoint? Is it even possible? Every time I try to change it in Access it tells me it can't be done since it's a linked table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary key is auto assigned, and unfortunately cannot be changed.